# Form-Clearing all the text and other components element when clicked on button

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have created a simple form with inputtext field, select options, radiobuttons and textArea.
I have even created 2 button, one for submit and one to 'Clear' all the text from the Form.
I can clear text from inputfield and the textarea's text,  I have created a callback function in parentClass (Form.js) and from there I have sended the data as props to TextArea.js class

```
       <TextArea
          callbackFromParent={this.parentCallback}
        />
```

and when i clicked on 'Clear All' button, the textInput field and textarea clears up.So i thought to implement in the same way for 'Select' option and for other components. 
So I created select variable in state and in callback function (parentCallback) setting the select again
and sending it as props to  component as callbackFromParent, but then i am setting this props value in state as : **selectCountry: this.props.callbackFromParent**, From Select component I have to send it to TextArea.js component as the 'Clear all' button is there as well the function for it.
I am stuck at this point and don't know exactly how to think or implement it. i have looked through Google but not got the answer I am looking for. I want to Clear each and every Form input field text and reset the select options, radiobuttons and so on.
I will be gratefull for all the help I can get. Thanks in Advance!

My code link: https://codesandbox.io/s/reactforms-w1y38

```
Form.js:

import React from "react";
import Select from "./Select";
import SelectGender from "./RadioButton";
import TextArea from "./TextArea";

class Form extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      value: "",
      select: ""
    };
  }

  onChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      value: e.target.value
    });
  };

  //Child to Parent — Use a callback and states
  // OR WE CAN SAY THAT PARENT NEED data FROM CHILD AND WE DO :
  parentCallback = () => {
    this.setState({
      value: "",
      select: ""
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>Child form</h3>
        <label>Enter name: </label>
        <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.onChange} />
        <p>You Entered: {this.state.value}</p>

        <Select callbackFromParent={this.parentCallback} />
        <SelectGender />
        <br />
        <TextArea
          callbackFromParent={this.parentCallback}
          //Data passing from parent to child
          dataFromParent={this.state.value}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Form;

-------------------------

Select.js

import React from "react";

class Select extends React.Component {
  state = {
    selectGenderOptions: ["Male", "Female", "Others"],
    selectCountry: this.props.callbackFromParent
  };

  render() {
    console.log("Select props", this.props);
    return (
      <div>
        <label>
          {/* <select selectGenderOptions={this.state.selectGenderOptions} /> */}
          Select Gender:
          <select>
            <option value="select" selected className="text-hide">
              {" "}
              {/*//change the Css style if you dnt want to hide the text */}
              Please select
            </option>
            <option value="male">Male</option>
            <option value="female">Female</option>
            <option value="other">Other</option>
          </select>
        </label>

        <label>
          <h3>Select Country</h3>
          <select>
            <option value="select" selected>
              {" "}
              Select Country{" "}
            </option>

            <option value="ind">India</option>
            <option value="pak">Pakistan</option>
            <option value="bang">Bangladesh</option>
            <option value="dub">Dubai</option>
            <option value="swe">Sweden</option>
            <option value="dan">Danmark</option>
            <option value="usa">USA</option>
            <option value="aus">Australia</option>
          </select>
        </label>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Select;

-----------------------------
TextArea.js

import React from "react";

class TextArea extends React.Component {
  state = {
    textAreaValue: "",
    inputValue: ""
  };

  textAreaHandler = event => {
    this.setState({ textAreaValue: event.target.value });
  };

  onSubmitHandler = () => {
    return `Your comment ${this.state.textAreaValue}`;
  };

  clearAllHandler = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      textAreaValue: "",
      inputValue: this.props.callbackFromParent(this.state.inputValue)
    });
  };

  // sendDataFromChild = () => {
  //   this.props.callbackFromParent();
  // };

  render() {
    console.log("inputvalue", this.props);
    console.log("callback", this.props.callbackFromParent);
    return (
      <div>
        <label>
          <h3>Comment:</h3>
          <textarea
            value={this.state.textAreaValue}
            placeholder="Write anything"
            onChange={this.textAreaHandler}
          />
        </label>
        <div>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" onClick={this.onSubmitHandler} />
          <button onClick={this.clearAllHandler}>Clear All</button>
        </div>
        <p>You wrote: {this.state.textAreaValue}</p>
        <p>Data Coming From Parent AS props: {this.props.dataFromParent}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default TextArea;
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed some stuff and re-work your code, please see all changes here https://codesandbox.io/s/reactforms-r6w6p?fontsize=14. I removed some fields to show you the basic idea, after that you should be able to apply it to other fields.

Explanation:

- First things first: react app has a single state, be sure that you don't create a state for every component (I removed all states except one in the `Form` component), now you have only one source of truth. Well actually you have one more state in `index.js` so you still need to do a small clean up and pass the state down to your `Form` component. I hope you got the idea.
- Events and values have to be passed as props from parent to child components (see how I done it for Select and ButtonRow), and then they have to be called like so `this.props.myFunc()`.
- Make your `select` controllable via attributes `value` and `onChange` event (see in the code).

Let me know if it's not what are you looking for.

Comment: Thanks you so much for the explainations, haven't tried yet but i will soon and let you know. thanks again!

Comment: S I have now completed the form and thanks for your help, when you said "so you still need to do a small clean up and pass the state down to your Form component." what did you meant exactly ? i have set the index state to 'title' and have passes that to Form.js as props. or did you meant something else. here is the link to my code: https://codesandbox.io/s/reactforms-k59d8

Comment: You did right, by "clean up" I meant that, currently, your state is inside of the form (local state of a component) and if you want to display data from input fields/radio buttons and so on somewhere outside of the form component, you cannot do that easily. If there is no need to do that just stick with your solution, otherwise take a look at https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html and see how state is used only in the top level component (FilterableProductTable) and gets passed to child components (code a bit old there but not the idea).

Comment: S, I have one issue though,I created a Modal component which shows on clicking the 'Submit' button and all the fields values in it. So far so good, but when I clicked on 'clear all' button , även the information in the MODAL component goes away, which I don't want. I wan to keep the information in modal and just clear the Html elements ( like textinputm select, radiobutton and so on). I don't understand the reason why it's behaving in this way. Will be gratefull for your help. My code: https://codesandbox.io/s/reactforms-k59d8

Comment: Please create another question for that, it seems it's not related to the current question

Comment: Ok Thanks for letting me know, I will create another question for this soon.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try changing:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onClick={this.onSubmitHandler} />
```

to:

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" onClick={this.onSubmitHandler} />
```

By default "submit" is going to try to submit the data and wait for a response. Setting it to a type of button to "button" should not try to submit anymore.

Comment: I have tried to set the input type="button", but its the same. My problem is I want to clear all the text from inputfield and set the checkbox and select option to 'reset', when clicked on 'Clear all' button. Thanks!